# why my Toast show null when get text from edittext field

Tags: android

In my code `Toast` show null value not show the `edittext` String value when I click the button. Please tell me what is the problem in this code.

```
String Serachvalue;
EditText  editText2;
ImageView imageView1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
editText2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
Serachvalue=editText2.getText().toString();
imageView1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

      Toast.makeText(HomeMenu.this, Serachvalue, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
    });
```

XMl

```
 <EditText
 android:id="@+id/editText2"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
 android:paddingTop="20dp"
 android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageView1"
 android:hint="  Search School By Name" >
 </EditText>
```

Comment: set your text. like editText2.settext("bal bla ") before calling Serachvalue=editText2.getText().toString();

Comment: Clean your project and try again. There is nothing seems to be wrong in your code.

Comment: do this `Serachvalue=editText2.getText().toString();` inside `onClickListener()`

Answer (score 0):

Move below single line inside onclick listner.

> Serachvalue=editText2.getText().toString();

like below@

```
imageView1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
      Serachvalue=editText2.getText().toString();
      Toast.makeText(HomeMenu.this, Serachvalue, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Assign your searchValue in the onclicklistener.I guess you are assigning ur search value in oncreate() , at that time your edittext will have null value when the activity is created.

Answer (score 0):

*Check the length before showing the text in a Toast*

First initialize the string as

```
String Serachvalue = "Please type something !";
```

then check the length and re initialize.

```
if(editText2.getText().toString().length()!=0)
        Serachvalue=editText2.getText().toString();
```